# Promise.all does not check for/store all promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have problem with promise.All not catching all the promises to resolve...

short example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    var promiseArray = [];

    function promiseResolve (data) {
        return new Promise (function (resolve) {
            resolve(data);
        });
    }

    var data1 = 1;

    promiseArray.push(promiseResolve(data1));

    var data2 = 2;

    promiseArray.push(promiseResolve(data2));

    var data3 = 3;

    promiseArray.push(promiseResolve(data3));

    console.log(promiseArray);

    **// all is fine**

    **// but when we add promise in some asynchronous operation like... request for example:**

    var test = request('https://www.google.com', function (err, res, content) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200)
        {
            promiseArray.push(promiseResolve(content));
            console.log(content);
        }
    });

    Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    **// it does not store promise in a array... I thought that at first promise.All always 'check' if all promises are stored, then execute those by resolve, reject...**

  res.render('index');
});
module.exports = router;
```

comment are in code, but long story short - promise.All does not check for/store all promises.

Some more text for SO 'algorithm'...  and more... and more... and more...

Comment: well, that last promise isn't in the array when you call `Promise.all(promiseArray)` - because it is added to the array asynchronously ..

Comment: also, your `promiseResolve` function is not required, as Promise.all can handle non-promises in the array

Comment: yea but I thought promise.All check/wait for all promises to be in array... but I guess it's not and it's default behavior... so I need to use callback or another promise?

Comment: no, it waits for all promises in the array to resolve - answer below is what you need - and, as I pointed out, you don't need the `promiseResolve` function for two reasons ... 1) `Promise.resolve` does the same thing and 2) Promise.all promisifies any non-promises in the array

Comment: `Promise.all` waits for all Promises that are in the array *at the moment `Promise.all` is called*, but not for Promises that happen to be added to the array later.

Comment: ahhh ok, got it now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time `Promise.all(promiseArray)` runs, `promiseArray` is only composed of the first three Promises - the fourth one from `request` does not get added to `promiseArray` until after the request goes through, by which time the `Promise.all` has already resolved. You'll have to explicitly construct a `Promise` for the `request` so that `promiseArray` has all necessary `Promises` before `Promise.all` is called:

```
promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request('https://www.google.com', function (err, res, content) {
    if (res.statusCode == 200) resolve(content);
    else reject('bad statusCode');
  });
}));
```